# R/shiny, 2 colours in the same box, datatable package

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, colors

I have a question,
I am creating a shiny application in R and I am using the "datatable" package to work on the visual. Do you know if it's possible to assign 2 colours for the same box ?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("TabFin")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  output$TabFin <- renderDataTable({
    vec1 <- c("cat","dog","human","cow","monkey")
    vec2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    tab <- data.frame(Nom=vec1,Num=vec2)  
    datatable(tab, class = 'cell-border stripe', filter = 'top') %>%
      formatStyle(
        'Nom', 'Num',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1, 2, 3), c('gray', 'green', 'blue')))
   
  })
}    

shinyApp(server=server,ui=ui)
```

For example, we can see that 1 is grey, 2 is green and 3 is blue. But how do you make 4 blue and green, i.e. the cow square is half green and half blue ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqmMM.png)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the guidance to create a working example to allow the community to engage with your inquiry: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution !

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("TabFin")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  output$TabFin <- DT::renderDataTable({
    vec1 <- c("chat","chien","homme","vache","singe")
    vec2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    tab <- data.frame(Nom=vec1,Num=vec2)  
    
    tab %>%
    datatable(class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              filter = 'top',
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                rowCallback = DT::JS(
                  'function(row, data) {
                            if (data[1] == 1)
                              $("td:eq(0)", row).css("background-color", "orange");
                            if (data[1] == 2)
                              $("td:eq(0)", row).css("background-color", "green");
                            if (data[1] == 3)
                              $("td:eq(0)", row).css("background", "linear-gradient(to right, skyblue, orange)");
                            if (data[1] == 4)
                              $("td:eq(0)", row).css("background", "linear-gradient(to right, skyblue, green)");
                            if (data[1] == 5)
                              $("td:eq(0)", row).css("background", "linear-gradient(to right, green, orange)");  
                  }'
                ) 
              )  
            )
  })
}    

shinyApp(server=server,ui=ui)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r6hf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a dummy column, to specify the colors you want, they can be conditional or explicit. We then simply going to hide that column(s), this approach is very flexible when you need to style multiple columns

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)


vec1 <- c("cat","dog","human","cow","monkey")
vec2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
vec3 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
colors <- c(1,1,1,1,2)
tab <- data.frame(Colors = colors,Nom=vec1,Num=vec2,Num3 = vec3)  

ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("TabFin")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
    
    output$TabFin <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(tab, class = 'cell-border stripe', filter = 'top',rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list(
                      columnDefs=list(
                          list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(0))
                      )
                  )
        ) %>%
            formatStyle(
                columns=c('Nom', 'Num'),
                valueColumns = 'Colors',
                backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1, 2), c('steelblue', 'lightgreen')))
        
    })
}    

shinyApp(server=server,ui=ui)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not quite what I need. I just added a picture to my question.

Comment: I don't think that is possible at this time